# Не работает маунт при загрузке

Tags: linux, archlinux

Настраивал автоподключение ресурса smb из локалки. Вручную всё работает прекрасно, а автоматически не запускается. 
systemctl status выдаёт

```
mnt-mounthere.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
июл 21 10:50:50 username systemd[1]: mnt-mounthere.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

Конфиг такой:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount Share at boot
Requires=systemd-networkd.service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=//192.168.X.X/username
Where=/mnt/mounthere
Options=credentials=/etc/samba/creds/username,uid=12345,gid=1001,noperm,nosetuids,iocharset=utf8,rw,x-systemd.automount
Type=cifs
TimeoutSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Подскажите, где может быть косяк?